# Console Output duplicating? C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

im working on a C++ program which asks for a username and password and then logs you in to a console (sort of). After logging in it displays what i have cout'ed in my code twice(MYCONSOLE: MYCONSOLE:). I didnt do a good job of explaining but hopefully my code will give you a better idea. Any idea of what my mistake is? 
PS please dont hate me if the solution is simple, im really new to this langauge. =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int successfullogin();
/*USERNAME:ROOT
  PASSWORD:TOOR*/

//Login Screen
int main() {
    string username;
    string password;
    cout << "Enter UserName: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << endl;
    if (username == "root") {
        cout << "Enter PassWord: ";
        cin >> password;
        if (password == "toor") {
            system("cls");
            cout << endl << "Login Successful... \n \nPlease wait while console is being initialised...";
            Sleep(5000);
            system("cls");
            successfullogin();
        }
        else {
            cout << endl << "Incorrect Password \a";
            system("color 4");
            _getch();
            system("cls");
            system("color f");
            main();
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect Username \a";
        system("color 4");
        _getch();
        system("cls");
        system("color f");
        main();
    }
}


//Console
int successfullogin()
{
    string input;
    input.clear();
    cout << "MYCONSOLE: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    if (input == "shutdown")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "MYCONSOLE: " << input << endl;
        _getch();
        system("cls");
        successfullogin();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't call `main` recursively, use *loops*. Same with the `successfullogin` function, use *loops*.

Comment: Maybe it could be a good idea to show the wrong output as part of the question

Comment: Also avoid calling `successfullogin` recursively

Comment: as in like a picture? @4386427

Comment: just as plain text so we can see exactly what is printed twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); in the successfullogin method will do the job.
Like this:

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
getline(cin,input);
```

According to the Notes in the Section of the Cpp Reference:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

You are mixing cin >> style with getline from cin.
This way it can happen that an new line char '\n' is not substituted from the cin stream and will return immediately by the getline call.

An nice way for the screen clear solution:

```
void clear(){
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO Info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &Info);
    SHORT Width = Info.srWindow.Right - Info.srWindow.Left + 1;
    for (SHORT N = Info.srWindow.Top; N <= Info.srWindow.Bottom; ++N) {
        DWORD Chars;
        COORD Pos = { Info.srWindow.Left, N };
        FillConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ' ', Width, Pos, &Chars);
        FillConsoleOutputAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0, Width, Pos, &Chars);
    }
    COORD TopLeft = { Info.srWindow.Left, Info.srWindow.Top };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), TopLeft);
}
```

Comment: To get rid of the recursions is a nice tip to, also what they did not mention is the system("cls") solution. This is a simple way of clearing the screen, but not very clever. More infos here: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/clearing-the-tui-screen.html

Comment: With a few changes to the windows filling example you will get a nice clear function. sry is to long for a single comment

Comment: yes, ive heard the system() command isnt too good. Although it seems to be harder to code it directly form the source file. @zinnjonas

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines

```
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

to the start of `successfullogin`

The problem seems to be that there are still something ready for you in `cin` so `getline` wil return immediately.

As mentioned in comments by Joachim Pileborg and myself, you should not do the recursive calls. Your `main` could instead be like:

```
int main() {
  while(1)    // Use an "endless" loop
  {
    string username;
    string password;
    cout << "Enter UserName: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << endl;
    if (username == "root") {
        cout << "Enter PassWord: ";
        cin >> password;
        if (password == "toor") {
            system("cls");
            cout << endl << "Login Successful... \n \nPlease wait while console is being initialised...";
            Sleep(5000);
            system("cls");
            successfullogin();

            break; // To end the while(1) loop
        }
        else {
            cout << endl << "Incorrect Password \a";
            system("color 4");
            _getch();
            system("cls");
            system("color f");
            // main(); remove line
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect Username \a";
        system("color 4");
        _getch();
        system("cls");
        system("color f");
        // main(); remove line
    }
  }
}
```

The same applies here

```
int successfullogin()
{
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
  while(1)
  {
    string input;
    input.clear();
    cout << "MYCONSOLE: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    if (input == "shutdown")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "MYCONSOLE: " << input << endl;
        _getch();
        system("cls");
        // successfullogin(); remove line
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got it, although does using loops make a difference in output or is it the same.

Comment: Did it work? It should give the same and solve an important problem also, i.e. your original code kept adding to the stack which would lead to stach overflow

Comment: Very bad - it'll crash the program

Comment: Wow, i'll make sure to use loops in the future. Thanks for that.